# Boost sleep inaccurate?

Tags: c++, boost, sleep

I'm experiencing strange issues with the `boost::this_thread::sleep_for` function. Whenever I try to sleep for longer periods of time the result is always inaccurate and the program sleeps longer than expected.

Here are some results:

```
sleep(360) -> sleeps around 378 seconds
sleep(180) -> sleeps around 189 seconds
sleep(100) -> sleeps around 105 seconds
```

The time it actually sleeps is around 5% more than what was intented.

I've tested on two different computers and the result is the same. When I test Standard Library's `std::this_thread::sleep_for` or Windows API's `Sleep` functions it works better.

I haven't been able to figure out the problem. Haven't been able to find anything on the internet or in the boost documentation. Any suggestions? What is the technical reason for this?

**See comments below for answers!**

Comment: `std::chrono` is better suited for precision time measurements

Comment: You should not rely on sleep precisely sleeping for any amount of time. Even when you'r not calling sleep, the OS can (will) schedule you in and out. So any reliance on it will cause problem. Rather, check the clock and accumulate elapsed time, if you need to do something at regular interval. e.g. if it's been an hour and you want to do something every second, then you should have done it 3600 times.

Comment: The actual technical reason for the rather large tolerance is here https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/970dcb8afd1eb470d1c99e74fc13d1dafaadc46d/src/win32/thread.cpp#L637-L659

Comment: for more context see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381866/boost-thread-wakes-up-too-late-in-1-58

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I wondered what was so different with boost's sleep, now I understand.